# (index):45 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined at (index):45

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, export, ejs

I am working in node.js. My basic goal is to pass an object from server js side to client side js 
I tried this

**on server side route**

```
router.get("/" , function(req,res){
var data = {name : "gohar" ,
             age : "21"}
res.render("landing" , {data : data})
});
```

**in EJS**

```
<h1>
This is landing page <%= data.name %>
</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
     console.log(data)
</script>
```

Comment: in ejs I even tried
console.log(<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>)
but its has some issues with the ejs brackets

Comment: Which line is line 45?

Comment: line 45 is the one with console.log(data)
in the script tags

Comment: Does the h1 display correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print in terminal you can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <% console.log(JSON.stringify(data) ) %>
</script>
```

If you want to print in browser console you can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>)
</script>
```

The error you are getting in IDE for ejs brackets is due to the fact that you have mentioned mimetype as text/javascript. Though the solution will work but to remove the errors you should change the type but then you won't be able to console log in your browser.

```
<script type="text/ejs">
    <% console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) %>
</script>
```